# Use case diagrams

Tags: use-case, functional-requirements

[image: USE CASE DIAGRAM]

I was asked to write a use case diagram based on a description/scenario
and I got a little confused when designing this use case because I doubted a little whether it's a functional or non-functional requirement (because I'm specifying how, not what)

In my case, the user shall be able to add transactions manually or automatically.

Would the above be a correct representation?

Answer (score 1):

No syntactically this is wrong: you can only associate use cases to actors and not to other use cases:

[image]

A better approach is to use inheritance, because adding automatically or manually are both specific cases of the more general case of adding transactions:

[image]

This being said, use cases should be goal oriented. Adding transactions could be a valid objective, but whether automatic or not seems a detail that is not necessary relevant at the level of the use case (i.e. could be better represented in the activity diagram that’ll model how the use case will work). It’s not forbidden to show this kind of details but it’s [functional decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419273/3723423) that leads to over-complicated diagrams where the big picture is lost.